# Error in running livy spark server in hue

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, hue

When I run following command

`hue livy_server`

Following error is shown

```
 Failed to run spark-submit executable: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have set SPARK_HOME=/home/amandeep/spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Livy on local mode it will except to find the spark-submit script in its environment. Check your shell PATH variable.

Comment: thanx that helped ... actually forgot to add path variable for spark_home/bin in bashrc