# Error Livy Spark Server hue 3.9

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, hue

I installed hue 3.9 on a cluster of 5 hosts with HDP 2.3. My Ambari  version is 2.1.2.

The problem is that the Hue initial setup screen displays:

> Spark The app will not work without a running Livy Spark Server

Several problems appeared earlier but I got to solve them.

Following this thread [Error in running livy spark server in hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014656/error-in-running-livy-spark-server-in-hue) and this web http://gethue.com/new-notebook-application-for-spark, I tried several things, but when I start livy-spark with root user I get the following error:

```
[root@m1 bin]# /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue livy_server
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hue/apps/spark/java-lib/livy-assembly.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Failed to run spark-submit executable: java.io.IOException: Unable to determing spark-submit version [1]:
```

If I execute `spark-submit` to /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/, it seems that there is no fault, it show me options of the command. And the `spark-submit --version` command displays spark's version correctly (1.4.1). 
Someone could help me?

Thank you and regards

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your **PATH** to point to /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/?  Such as

```
# export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/"
# /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue livy_server
```

Comment: Thanks about your reply. Yes, I have set the path to that directory but not working.